# PHP How get parametr from object?

Tags: php, date

When I do `var_dump()` I get this response

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) { 
["date"]=> string(19) "2003-07-01 13:38:43" 
["timezone_type"]=> int(3) 
["timezone"]=> string(11) "Asia/Muscat" }
```

Tell me, please, how I can output parameter **date** from this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to simply use

```
echo $dateObject->date;
```

Otherwise, look into the [`DateTime#format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method

```
echo $dateObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// => 2003-07-01 13:38:43
```

This is a little nicer because it allows you to format the output however you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

I you have a look at the result of var_dump, you will see that you are dealing with an instance of DateTime class:

> object(DateTime)#1 (3) {

Knowing that, you should go to the PHP class reference and have a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

There you will find how to use this particular class. If you have a look at the method list you will find a method DateTime::format, which is the one you need. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$datetime = new Datetime();
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Look http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php